# What about the children?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

In Jessica Jones, season 1, episode 2 (AKA Crush Syndrome), Kilgrave has the two children shut themselves in a closet. Is there any information (word of god, expanded universe, etc.) on what happened to them?

Comment: [They ded](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EYMPzYXvjZw/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: "Somebody please think of the children!" - Maud Flanders